# Use scope variable in a markup using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

could someone please explain me the difference between these two piece of code, and the way to manage it.

Here is my **index.html**

```
<body ng-app="docsIsolateScopeDirective">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
  <my-customer info="naomi" ></my-customer>
  {{nameUser}}
  <my-customer info="igor"></my-customer>
</div>
</body>
```

Here is my **script.js**

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('docsIsolateScopeDirective', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.nameUser = 'naomi';
    $scope.naomi = { name: 'Naomi', address: '1600 Amphitheatre' };
    $scope.igor = { name: 'Igor', address: '123 Somewhere' };
  }])
  .directive('myCustomer', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        customerInfo: '=info'
      },
      templateUrl: 'my-customer-iso.html'
    };
  });
})(window.angular);
```

And finally my **my-customer-iso.html** :

```
Name: {{customerInfo.name}} Address: {{customerInfo.address}}
```

The result is this :

```
Name: Naomi Address: 1600 Amphitheatre
naomi Name: Igor Address: 123 Somewhere
```

Question is : I would like to set the info of my  markup with a scope variable (basically $scope.nameUser which contains "naomi"). But when I write

```
<my-customer info={{nameUser}} </my-customer> // or <my-customer info="{{nameUser}}"> </my-customer>
```

instead of

```
<my-customer info= "naomi"></my-customer>
```

the code is broken and I don't understand why.. Is the scope variable can't be consider like a string ? Thanks

EDIT : Even if I write :

```
<my-customer info = nameUser> </my-customer>
```

The result is still different. I don't receive an error but the output is :

```
Name: Address:
Name: Igor Address: 123 Somewhere
```

So I think that I'm missing something about the interaction between the controller and the directive. See here : https://plnkr.co/edit/hbi4whoH3Dj9lDV3vVzZ?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `<my-customer info={{nameUser}} </my-customer>` just use `<my-customer info="nameUser" </my-customer>`. You don't need the `{{ }}`

UPDATE:

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve. In your example, you are trying to pass a simple string 'naomi', but your directive expects an object with the following structure:

```
customerInfo = {
   name: "",
   address: ""
};
```

So, if you want to have it working, you should make your scope object look like this:

```
$scope.nameUser = { name: 'XXX', address: 'YYY' };
```

and then pass it to the directive like so:

```
<my-customer info="nameUser" ></my-customer>
```

Take a look at [this plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/zRi3pLGpT8geoZtT9GNi?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work. I don't receive an error, but the result is "Name: Address:"

Comment: I've updated my answer, could please please clarify this for me?

Comment: Ok I understand my mistake now. I thought "naomi" were a string that refers to $scope.naomi and not the object itself. Thank you for your explanation

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an important difference here to note. In your directive you use "=info" for scope `customerInfo` attribute assignment in your directive. The `=` means assignment by reference. Therefore you cannot use `{{}}` as it is an evaluation expression. So for example, if you have used

```
customerInfo: '@info'
```

your code would work fine. Because '@' binds property to the evaluated value instead. 
Or, otherwise, just remove `{{}}` evaluation expression from `<my-customer info={{nameUser}} </my-customer>`  to be

```
<my-customer info="nameUser"> </my-customer>
```

In addition, the empty output you receive, is because `$scope.nameUser` is a string, but you are expecting an object with `name` and `address` attributes in your directive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please have a look on the edit

Comment: Ok I understand my mistake now. I thought "naomi" were a string that refers to $scope.naomi and not the object itself. Thank you for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

When assigning isolated scopes, the value passed (info="naomi") reflects an assigned property of the parent scope. The interpolation handlebars will not work here. Drop off the handlebars, leaving 'info="nameUser"' should do the trick. Just remember that nameUser is just a string while naomi was an object. So naomi.name yielded a string but nameUser.name doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I'm right, the property "nameUser" comes from the parent scope . So how can I solve this ?